# Longitudinal ordinal categorical data

Tags: r, mixed, ordinal

I'm working with longitudinal data and I'm expected to use mixed effects logistic regression model. And some of my fixed variables are categoricas, but in addition are ordinal.

The doubts that have been brought, if there would be problems in modeling considering they were ordinals. I'm working with R

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. Ordinal variables are usually stored as `ordered` class, which is a special type of the `factor` class. See `?factor` or `?ordered`.

Comment: You might find the [`ordinal` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clmm2_tutorial.pdf) helpful. Also [this summary](https://gist.github.com/casallas/8263818) of R packages and functions for multinomial regression.